# How do I find the Ebony Warrior?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

How do I find the Ebony Warrior in Skyrim? I have been searching for him for ages, and a friend of mine said he met him at level 20 on the Skyrim Legendary Edition.  I still don't know where he is, and my friend said he normally finds him in Windhelm. Is this true, or is he a random occurrence?

I'm playing on the Xbox 360.

Comment: I'm afraid your friend has been pulling your leg: there's no way he found him legitimately with a level 20 character.

Answer (score 8):

The Ebony Warrior will only appear once you have reached level 80. Once you're level 80, he will approach you if you're in any [major city](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Cities), not just Windhelm.

> Upon reaching level 80 a mysterious warrior wearing a full suit of
>   ebony armor [The Ebony Warrior] will approach you in any major city and challenge you to a
>   duel at his Last Vigil. The quest will then update to give his
>   location, a camp northeast of Fort Greenwall. The Ebony Warrior will
>   not attack you when approached, and will not speak. He will simply
>   stand, brandishing his sword as a clear invitation. You must initiate
>   the attack for the battle to begin. Make sure that you are prepared
>   for one serious fight. It is advised to wear the strongest armor you
>   can get and have plenty of potions at the ready. You may want to bring
>   a follower as well.

Source: [The Ebony Warrior, UESP wiki](http://uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:The_Ebony_Warrior)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can randomly encounter him in Skyrim at any lvl, just don't expect to win so easily. I've found him mining in the mountains, walking the roads, multiple times all before lvl 80. he will ignore you unless you attack first.

Comment: I think you're referring to mercenaries wearing ebony armour.